# No sound from sequencer in certain scene

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, audio

I have a blend with two scenes, and the same audio strip is in both sequence editors. One scene has sound and the other one doesn’t, even though both strips are unmuted and have volume at 1. I vaguely remember having done this on purpose a long time ago (with this file), but I don’t remember where. Any thoughts on things to check?

[The blend file, on OneDrive.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgH_S_5HSwNXhnbqhhV0fLRvTkNH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Playback* settings of the *Sequencer* you have enabled *Mute* in the scene without sound.

[image: mute playback]

Comment: Thank you, and God bless!