# No sound in Blender VSE, not a problem of volume or moved files. There's also a weird black line

Tags: video-sequence-editor, blend-files, audio

I know you're gonna send me to a previous post but I tried them and it didn't work, also, my problem didn't seem to be similar.

I noted that for people having the problem of not having sound in Blender, the problem generally turned out to be to a file being moved or the sound being at 0.

But in my case, I have this problem for any sound file that I want to add, there's just no sound that plays. I also have a weird black line in the middle of my track which none of the tutorials and screenshots I saw have.

The problem isn't that the sound is silent at the start, there should music immediately when I press play.

I only have this problem in Blender, I perfectly have sound on Chrome, on Vegas Pro and on my audio player.

I made a small video of it here (10s):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSWDC.jpg

There's just no sound and a weird black line.

I need help.

EDIT: Click on the image to go on the page to download (Blender 2.93.0) [image]

If you're experimented or just know Blender VSE, you can download my blender file right over this sentence and try to see what the actual problem might be.

Comment: Screenshoot the black line. Check the “View” menu for sound in the sequencer.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230304/73575 You may not have tried this “it.”

Comment: The "Mute" box wasn't checked for me. Checking or unchecking it doesn't seem to change anything
https://imgur.com/a/pcDtzNo

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "screenshot the blackline"? What key is that, screenshot?

Comment: As far as I know, blender does not have an in box screen shooting tool, but most operating systems do. Screenshot the black line, and add that image to your post. “… and a weird black line“ is not very much detail to work with.

Comment: Please use the built-in image adding system rather than external links, even though the built-in system does use Imgur

Comment: OK, I viewed the GIF, but I don’t know where the line you’re talking about is. Also, is it possible that these music files just do not have sound for the first few seconds?

Comment: I know, some of these sound like really stupid questions. Maybe you should just upload your file with blend-exchange.com and we can look at it directly.

Comment: No, these music files do have sound in the first few seconds, I verified on the audio player. 
Concerning the black line, I'm talking about that black, vertical line in the middle of track on which the cursor, which is also vertical with a blue tip indicating the seconds, loops back to the frame 0 when it reaches it.

Comment: Oh. That’s not anything wrong, that’s just the end of the frame range.

Comment: Anyway, here's my blend file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ZKKe2LNY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ZKKe2LNY/) (Blender 2.93.0) Because the black line might not be wrong but I still mysteriously have no sound :/

Comment: did you ever try with another Blender version? what Blender version do u have?

Comment: I am on Blender 2.93.0
I doubt this is a problem related to this version, why would an entire version not have sound that doesn't make sense, and other people would have had the same problem way before me

Comment: Can someone experimented download my blender file and try to see what's the actual problem?

Answer (score 2):

Switching the audio device in user preferences sometimes fixes this issue.

What I usually do is:

- go to user preferences
- click on system
- on the sound dropdown, change the audio device to anything else, then switch back.

that resets Blender's audio and should fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure an audio codec is selected.  It is off by default.

Goto *Scene-> Encoding > Audio  > Audio Codec*

If it has *No Audio*, then select a codec, *MP3* worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually didn't solve it, I just created a brand new project, put the sound in Blender VSE first. It worked. So I just did all my layout and shading again.
Idk what the problem was but I found a way around it